# Clarify Class inheritance or Initiation?

Tags: c++, class

```
Handler::Handler(std::string c, std::string t, std::string req,std::string sub, _MaX *map)
: receiver(s1,s2,s3,"") , publisher_req(s1, s2, s3, "")
{
    Body
}
```

I wish to know is this a class inheritance technique or initializing technique in c++?

Comment: Well are `receiver` and `publisher_req` base classes or members?

Comment: This very much looks like the definition of a constructor, so it is an initialization. Whether there is inheritance in the game, cannot be said by this snippet alone.

Comment: Based on the colors (blue and black) in the code (which could depend on the editor of course :p), my best guess is that both receiver and publisher_req are class members which you initialize upon construction of a Handler instance. Whether this is called "initialization technique" is another question.